# How to change the color of text on click of radio - Angular

Tags: html, angular

I am designing a quiz component, I have an issue when revealing the solution using a submit button. I have a variable `checked` which is initially false.

Once the condition of right answer is met, checked is turned to true and the color is changed.

The problem is when I click reveal solution, all the answers go green. And when I click reveal solution again it stays green.

So
what I want :

When the user presses the correct answer and presses reveal solution, the answer should be green or else the selected answer should be red.

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Quiz } from './ez-quiz.types';
import { Subject, takeUntil } from 'rxjs';
import { QuizService } from './ez-quiz.service';

class answerDataStructure {
  check: boolean;
  value: string;
  expanded: boolean;
  constructor(answers) {
    this.value = answers;
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-ez-quiz',
  templateUrl: './ez-quiz.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ez-quiz.component.scss'],
})
export class EzQuizComponent implements OnInit {
  expand_button: boolean = false;
  private _unsubscribeAll: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();
  quiz: Quiz;
  options: answerDataStructure[] = [];
  checked: boolean = false;
  selectedAnswer: any[] = [];
  constructor(private quizService: QuizService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.quizService.Quiz$.pipe(takeUntil(this._unsubscribeAll)).subscribe(
      (quiz: Quiz) => {
        this.quiz = quiz;
        for (var answers of this.quiz[0].options) {
          let ansData = new answerDataStructure(answers);
          console.log(ansData);
          this.options.push(ansData);
        }
      }
    );
  }

  expand_and_check(correctAnswer: any) {
    //Expanded Condition
    if (this.expand_button == false) {
      this.expand_button = true;
      this.selectedAnswer.reverse();
      if (correctAnswer == this.selectedAnswer[0]) {
        console.log('Correct Answer'), (this.checked = true);
      } else if (this.selectedAnswer.length == 0) {
        console.log('Please select one answer');
      } else {
        console.log('Wrong Answer'), (this.checked = false);
      }
    } else {
      this.expand_button = false;
    }
  }

  changed(event: any, value: any) {
    this.selectedAnswer.push(value);
    console.log(event);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <!-- 1st Question -->
  <div class="questionStyle">
    {{ quiz[0].questionId }}{{ quiz[0].question }}
  </div>

  <section class="question-section">
    <ol>
      <mat-radio-group>
        <li *ngFor="let answers of options; let j = index">
          <mat-radio-button
            class="option-style-margin"
            [value]="answers.value"
            (change)="changed($event, j)"
          >
            <span [style.color]="checked ? 'green' : 'black'">
              {{ answers.value }}
            </span>
          </mat-radio-button>
        </li>
      </mat-radio-group>
    </ol>
  </section>

  <section class="pageMargin">
    <!--Buttons Margin and Button Placing-->

    <div class="buttonsMargin">
      <button
        mat-raised-button
        color="primary"
        (click)="expand_and_check(quiz[0].correctAnswer)"
      >
        <span class="buttonStyle">Reveal Solution</span></button
      >&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <button mat-raised-button color="warn">
        <span class="buttonStyle"> Labs</span>
        <mat-icon svgIcon="heroicons_outline:beaker"></mat-icon>
      </button>
    </div>

    <mat-card *ngIf="expand_button" class="mat-card">
      <mat-card-title>Explanation</mat-card-title>
      <mat-card-content>
        <p class="matContent">
          Both private and public cloud solutions are useful in various
          scenarios. Private clouds have restricted access to services whereas
          the public cloud is accessible to any user. A private cloud is most
          often connected to the Internet and works the same way as a public
          cloud when it comes to security and Azure management. Private clouds
          can have access to all Azure features too.
        </p>
      </mat-card-content>
    </mat-card>
  </section>
  <!--End of Question 1-->
</div>
<!--End of the Page-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Try having a separate function to get the color, and a separate variable to indicate correctness:

```html
<span [style.color]="getColor(j)">{{ answers.value }}</span>
```

```js
  correct = false;
  selectedIndex = -1;

  getColor(index: number) {
    if (!this.checked || index != this.selectedIndex) return 'black';
    if (this.correct) return 'green';
    return 'red';
  }

  changed(event:any,value:any){
      this.selectedIndex = value;
      this.selectedAnswer.push(value);
      console.log(event)
  }
```

Then your submit function becomes:

```js
  expand_and_check(correctAnswer: any) {
    //Expanded Condition
    if (this.expand_button == false) {
      this.expand_button = true;
      this.selectedAnswer.reverse();
      if (correctAnswer == this.selectedAnswer[0]) {
        console.log('Correct Answer');
        this.checked = true;
        this.correct = true;
      } else if (this.selectedAnswer.length == 0) {
        console.log('Please select one answer');
      } else {
        console.log('Wrong Answer');
        this.checked = true;
        this.correct = false;
      }
    } else {
      this.expand_button = false;
      this.checked = false;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hi when i select the wrong one or right one , the corresponding color does come but applies to each and every option. Is it due to the ngFor I used for answers.value.

Comment: Yes, your html applies applies `[style.color]` to all options. If you want to change only the selected answer you will need to create another variable `selectedIndex`, save the index in the `changed` function, pass the index `j` to `getColor()` and only return the color if `j === this.selectedIndex`.

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy for the help.Really helpful for me.